# Radio button or an image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a react application.

I have this requirement to show a switch similar to the one used in an iPhone setting.

I am able to use two images based on the on/off state and display it.

Is it better to create a component using input type=checkbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes AFAIK, that's how most of the ui library does it. They do it by using label html tag and hiding `checkbox` and using css selectors to know when to display on/off state. Checkboxes are a very powerfull concepts in HTML. You can check [this](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/) article from css-tricks which where the checkboxes can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an image for this:

```css
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Rounded switch -->
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

I took it from here: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp)

[edit] A one that looks more similar to the iphone switch

```css
.form-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.form-switch i {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  width: 46px;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 23px;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.form-switch i::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 42px;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 11px;
  transform: translate3d(2px, 2px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
}

.form-switch i::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 11px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transform: translate3d(2px, 2px, 0);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.form-switch:active i::after {
  width: 28px;
  transform: translate3d(2px, 2px, 0);
}

.form-switch:active input:checked + i::after { transform: translate3d(16px, 2px, 0); }

.form-switch input { display: none; }

.form-switch input:checked + i { background-color: #4BD763; }

.form-switch input:checked + i::before { transform: translate3d(18px, 2px, 0) scale3d(0, 0, 0); }

.form-switch input:checked + i::after { transform: translate3d(22px, 2px, 0); }
```

```html
<label class="form-switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <i></i>
  Select Me
</label>
```

source: [cssscript](https://www.cssscript.com/realistic-ios-switch-pure-css/)